# How can I raise an error for unpermitted params, but allow specific ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have added the following to my `application.rb` because I want to have control over all the sent parameters:

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

This way I see pretty fast during development if I have forgotten to allow a parameter, or something like that.

But - now I get the following error when trying to update a user through a form:

```
found unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, commit, locale, id
```

I'm a bit unsure on how to proceed: indeed these are parameters I didn't care about before, and they are automatically sent by Rails' `form_for`, as far as I can see.

I only want to care about the parameters of my resources, e.g. `user[name]`, `user[email]`, etc.

Is there a way to generally allow those unpermitted parameters above? Or do I miss an important point?

**Update**

As the problem doesn't seem to be reproduceable, here's the repository with the specific commit:

https://github.com/jmuheim/base/commit/dbb62dd68a8a243d056457c9093a6cd8ea3e3836

Just start the server, load the page, sign up as a user (or use `josh` with pw `joshjosh` from the seeds), then go to users > list users, and edit your user. Then you will get the error.

You can also just do `$ rake` and look at the failing specs.

Interesting is that the error is **not** raised when signing up, so I guess it has something to do with the `UsersController`. Maybe an issue with [inherited resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources)?

Comment: It might be just me, but rails ignores those default params when I turn the option on. I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim I think your issue lies with your specific app. I know that sounds obvious, but as others said, it should be reproducible in any situation. I recommend not asking the community to launch your app locally, as that violates the flag "what am I doing wrong?" and putting the burden of debugging onto us, the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

I found this: https://github.com/rafael/rails/commit/c197a7dc418cd4fe07131a41a44c8ddb66258801.

According to it, a config `always_permitted_parameters` can be set as follows:

```
# application.rb
config.action_controller.always_permitted_parameters = %w( controller action locale utf8 authenticity_token commit )
```

I don't know why I have to set this manually, while nobody else seems to have a similar issue.

Oh, and just for completeness, here's how I generally handle params:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ...stuff...

  private

  def user_params
    permitted_keys = [:name,
                      :email,
                      :password,
                      :password_confirmation,
                      # etc.
                      :lock_version]

    params.require(:user).permit permitted_keys
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just played with your application and have managed to reproduce your issue. And if I understand you question correctly here is what I want to say:

1. `Sign up` is processed by `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`. That is why it doesn't fail.

---

2. It also fails when in the dashboard you click `Users -> Create user`. From logs:

   ```
   Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
   ...
   [1] base(#<UsersController>) »  params
   => {
     "controller" => "users",
     "action" => "new",
     "locale" => "en"
   }
   ```

   Though its just a `#new` action so there is no need to check permitted params.
   I think you should investigate about this in `inherited resources` docs.

---

3. And here comes the solution for the `edit` issue right from rails [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters):

   ```
   params.require(:user).permit(
                    :name,
                    :email,
                    :avatar,
                    :avatar_cache,
                    :remove_avatar,
                    :about,
                    :password,
                    :password_confirmation,
                    :lock_version
                  )
   ```

   3.1 **But**

   As I found out this is not going to work with `inheried_resources` just like above. Try search for 'If you need params.require' on the docs [page](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources). One of their suggestions is:

   ```
   def permitted_params
     {
       user: params.require(:user).permit(
         :name,
         :email,
         :avatar,
         :avatar_cache,
         :remove_avatar,
         :about,
         :password,
         :password_confirmation,
         :lock_version
       )
     }
   end
   ```

---

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a look at it soon. I mark you as the correct answer so you get the bounty.